# Is Simic Ascendancy triggered by Awakening of Vitu-Ghazi?

Tags: magic-the-gathering

Does [Awakening of Vitu-Ghazi](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bAwakening%20of%20Vitu-Ghazi%5d) trigger the ability of [Simic Ascendancy](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bSimic%20Ascendancy%5d)?

Awakening of Vitu-Ghazi says:

> Put nine +1/+1 counters on target land you control. It becomes a legendary 0/0 Elemental creature with haste named Vitu-Ghazi.

So either the land gets the +1/+1 counters and **afterwards** becomes a creature.
Or it becomes a creature and then receives the +1/+1 counters.

To me the last assumption seems correct because it is irritating to me to be able to put +1/+1 counters on a land.

Comment: It was probably done that way to avoid the situation where you temporarily have a 0/0 creature. It wouldn't be a problem because SBAs aren't checked during the resolution of a spell, but it would confuse some people.

Comment: @ikegami well amass does exactly do this. Create a 0/0 token and then put +1/+1 counters on it.

Comment: Amass was probably done that way to keep the text short. It avoids an entire "otherwise" clause.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The two actions (adding counters and the permanent type change) are two different steps of the same spell. That means they're executed separately:

> 608.2c The controller of the spell or ability follows its instructions in the order written.

There's no rule prohibiting +1/+1 counters on a non-creature permanent. For example, the land [Llanowar Reborn](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bLlanowar%20Reborn%5d) enters the battlefield with a +1/+1 counter.

So unfortunately Simic Ascendancy wouldn't trigger, as the counters are put on the land while it's not a creature yet.

Simic Ascendancy *would* trigger if the land was already also a creature prior to the spell resolving: for example, casting Awakening a second time on the same animated land, or casting it on a land that was animated by [Nissa, Who Shakes the World](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bNissa%2c%20Who%20Shakes%20the%20World%5d).

Comment: damn. thanks for clarification, I thought I was on something there ☺

Comment: @bautista however if you animate it first with Nissa, then cast awakening, it does work...

Comment: And of course, there's always Dryad Arbor

Comment: @ike but unfortunately not standard legal